# run 2 or more cmd command using system() in C++

Tags: c++, cmd

I want to do two steps in my c++ program using system().

1. open the folder  system("cd /d ...")
2. run another program.exe

However, it seems like when I run step2, the folder opened in step1 is already closed.
What can I do to make sure that the folder won't be closed, so that I can use another cmd call to run .exe?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, you're going to need to expand on this a little and show us some of the code that you've written to solve your problem. Have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give you an indication of what to copy-paste

Comment: The `cd` command used in the `system()` call will change the directory only for the sub shell opened, not for your actual process.

Comment: You need to put both steps in one `system()` command and how that is done will be platform dependant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use

```
system("command1; command2; command3");
```

or

```
system("command1 && command2 && command3");
```

Refer To The following link: 
[Using a Single system() Call to Execute Multiple Commands in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245600/using-a-single-system-call-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-c)