# system() command does not detect the extension I want. Program detects "set path" but cannot the path

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char path[]="\"set path=C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\""; //the extension I want to path
    system(path);                                         //the command
    system("UnRAR x filename.rar");                       
}
```

OUTPUT

```
'UnRAR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

it works when i try it myself in cmd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run 2 or more cmd command using system() in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401051/run-2-or-more-cmd-command-using-system-in-c)

Comment: *at least* specify the operating system you are working on (probaly DOS-based) . The OS is not part of the C standard.

Comment: why don't use `system("\"C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\UnRAR\" x filename.rar");` to avoid setting PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to `system()` starts a fresh shell, and so things like environment variables don't carry over from one to the next.

You need to include both commands in one `system()` call.  According to [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd) it looks like you can separate them by `&`, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with the solution that you give in the first sentence, but it couldn't solve but ı could figure out and solve thanks to the link that you gave thanks mate!