# Compile and run Java programs using simple C program

Tags: java, c++, c, cmd

I have this problem:

To complile and run Java programs I must do the following:

In cmd.exe run comand

```
path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin
```

Then I must complile program:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Java\HelloWorld>javac HelloWorld.java
```

...and run:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Java\HelloWorld>java HelloWorld
```

In order not to follow these steps, I write simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _JAVA
#define JAVAC

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char comand[261];
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error: not enougth arguments. Example: %s <java program name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    system("path \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_75\\bin\"");
#ifdef JAVA
    sprintf(comand, "java \"%s\"\0", argv[1]);
#elif defined JAVAC
    sprintf(comand, "javac \"%s\"\0", argv[1]);
#else
#error must defined JAVA or JAVAC
#endif
    system(comand);
    return 0;
}
```

But it is not work: cmd does not see "java" or "javac".

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you add `java` and `javac` to your `environment variables` ?

Comment: I do this using comand path, not?

Comment: You can do it with the `control panel`. Just google it.

Comment: I assume that the second `system()` cannot see the modification of the `path` variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245600/using-a-single-system-call-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-c and try to run both commands in a single `system()` call.

Comment: Each system command is likely to be stand alone.  I would use a shell or batch script to do this.

Comment: Agree that 'system' efect is lost. I never see such path syntax, always write with =. Program has many defect, i.e. not diagnose errors, I don't understand #define. User normal BAT command

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the path using Control panel because, if you set path using command prompt this will set the path temporarily when command prompt closed the path also destroy so set it permanently using

> Control Panel\System and Security\System>Advance system setting > Environment variable > and in system variable add path may this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a C program, just use a few batch scripts.  First is the one to set the path variable **jpath.bat**.  Whenever you install a new SDK, this is all you need to change.  You do not need to change any environment variables.  This sets it every time.  You could have different ones for different SDKs.  Java isn't as universal as everyone hopes: sometimes there are version dependencies, especially when it gets to jar files.

```
@path "%programfiles%\java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin";%path%
```

Next is a script to do the building **jbuild.bat**

```
@setlocal
@call jpath.bat
rem add -cp and any jar files before the %1
javac %1
@endlocal
```

Next is a script to run the code **jrun.bat**

```
@setlocal
@call jpath.bat
rem add -cp and any jar files before %1
java %1
@endlocal
```

To use

```
jbuild HelloWorld.java
jrun HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

For permanent solution of `java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin` path, it is highly recommended to set an environment path in Control Panel as answered by Abhijit Kumbhar.

If you still don't know what to do, for temporary solution, you should create a  new text file in the same folder of your program and edit it with a `.bat` extension and edit the contents by adding in each line as following...

```
set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin"
javac programname.java
java programname
pause
```

You can edit the `.bat` file with the required programname and run it. This could prevent the tedious job of opening cmd every time and compiling and running the code. Basically, a `.bat` file does it for you every time you run it.

**Edit:** If you have already set a permanent path in environment variables, then you only have to use the last 3 lines(*except first*) in your `.bat` file. This will still save your time opening a cmd window and typing tedious commands over and over again.