# C++ execute many commands in shell

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have a C++ program from which I want to execute multiple commands in a shell.
My current solution use the system() function and looks like this:

```
return_value = system(SETUP_ENVIRONMENT; RUN_USEFUL_APP_1);
... do_something_else ...
return_value = system(SETUP_ENVIRONMENT; RUN_USEFUL_APP_2);
... do_something_else ...
return_value = system(SETUP_ENVIRONMENT; RUN_USEFUL_APP_3);
...
```

It works, but SETUP_ENVIRONMENT takes a few seconds making the program really slow. But I have to run it every time since system() runs in a new shell each time.
I want to be able to setup my shell once and then run all commands in it.

```
execute_in_shell(SETUP_ENVIRONMENT);
return_value = execute_in_shell(RUN_USEFUL_APP_1);
... do_something_else ...
return_value = execute_in_shell(RUN_USEFUL_APP_2);
... do_something_else ...
return_value = execute_in_shell(RUN_USEFUL_APP_3);
...
```

How do I do that?

I'm on Linux.

Comment: You could open a shell in a pipe and send the commands through it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245600/using-a-single-system-call-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-c

Comment: @mstruebing: That presumes that you know up front which programs to run, when, and with which arguments. The pipe is a better solution.

Comment: How do I open a shell in a pipe? Can I see return codes if I do that?

Comment: @oskla129 `system`'s return value indicates whether the command could be executed at all, not the command's result.

Comment: @molbdnilo According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/ 
"If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command, if supported."

Comment: @oskla129 I misremembered, apparently.

Comment: What does `SETUP_ENVIRONMENT` exactly do?

Comment: In this case 'SETUP_ENVIRONMENT' sets up a python virtualenv and installs a program in that environment using pip. My first solution was to do the setup before executing my program. It worked fine but I want to be able run it without any special commands. I will go with Michael's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three reasonable options for doing this, depending on your specific need.

If the various calls you make to external tools are part of coherent routine, then you can – and probably should – follow @dmi's advice and write a short shell script that you can call from your C++ program.

If you instead need to start procedures here and there, you might be interested into running the *shell* as an inferior process and attaching your program to it – so that instead of talking with your terminal, the shell process talks to your C++ program.

This method is not very difficult but has a few gotchas (for instance, some programs like *ssh,* *sudo* or *docker* may expect to be attached to a *tty*).  It is very well covered in most introductions to system programming (look for *inter process communication* and subprocesses) for any Unix variant. Let me outline that procedure:

1. use the pipe system call to create pipes (stdin_r, stdin_w)
2. use the pipe system call to create pipes (stdout_r, stdout_w)
3. use the pipe system call to create pipes (stderr_r, stderr_w)
4. use the fork system call to duplicate your program
5. In the child, you close stdin_w, stdout_r, stderr_r, and use the
    exec system call parametrised by stdin_r, stdout_w, stderr_w to
    run the shell.
6. In the parent, you close stdin_r, stdout_w, stderr_w, and you
    can now write commands in stdin_w, and read command output from
    stdout_r and stderr_r.

(This intentionally very sketchy, I included the outline only so that you are sure you found the right place in your favourite textbook).

There are third party libraries implementing all that low-level stuff for you. You can use [boost::process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) (which is not yet an official part of boost now) whose usage is illustrated with a [full tutorial](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.pipeline). There are [plenty of alternatives](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost%5Fwiki/wiki.pl?BoostProcess/ExistingLibraries) such as [pstreams](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net).

The third option would be to avoid using the shell and executing directly shell commands you use. This is the approach followed by [Rashell](https://github.com/michipili/rashell), an OCaml library defining primitives allowing to reliably compose sub-processes, which you can use for your own inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to answer 1, you could also use your program to create a shell script which will run all your useful programs and execute this script at once. Then the shell won't be started each time for each particular useful program.

Comment: I am not sure what the setting environment is, but as I understood, the most of time is consumed exactly by it, right? Perhaps then you could set the required environment for your main process, and then all spawned processes will inherit it automatically so, that you don't need to set it up for each particular useful program? or think over some other way to share the environment to them if possible (i.e. via a file or shared memory)